# Alternative for PowerRepresentations[n, x, 1]

Tags: performance-tuning, number-theory, number-representation

I am looking for numbers $n$ that can be written as the sum of other numbers. So: `PowersRepresentations[n, x, 1]`. But is there a faster way of finding these numbers? And is there a way to do the same calculation but with multiplication instead of addition?

Comment: Have you explored `IntegerPartitions`  for the case of addition?

Comment: For the case of multiplication you would need the prime factors